Luxon time zone abbreviations with Australia
I am using DateTime with from 'luxon' to display timezones on my application, it is all displaying properly and I am using the .toFormat('ZZZZ') according to the luxon docs and getting back a abbreviation for most places.
This is the line of code:
{DateTime.now().setZone(timezone).toFormat('ZZZZ')}

for timezone I am displaying it as follows:
America/Denver --> MDT
However my problem is whenever I try to do any times with Australia it is displayed as follow
Australia/Sydney --> GMT +10
Australia/Perth --> GMT +8
Is there a way to adjust so that is displays as its proper abbreviation? such as AEDT? and AWST? And not the comparison to GMT
